# Having issues in Jmeter while performing the IF Controller, i'm using Jmeter latest version 5.5

Tags: jmeter

INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JavaSampler: Created class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.JavaTest. Uses tearDownTest:
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
DEBUG o.a.j.c.IfController:     >> evaluate Expression [$(RESULTS) == COMPLETED] equals (ignoring case) 'true'
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Answer (score 2):

What "issues" you are "having"?

If you want the If Controller to execute its children when `RESULTS` JMeter Variable will be equal to `COMPLETED` you need to change it a little bit.

Your `$(RESULTS) == COMPLETED` condition doesn't make any sense, you need to change it to i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3):

```
${__jexl3("${RESULTS}" == "COMPLETED",)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri For the solution it is working fine now, Actually I am new on Jmeter so its really helpful for me.